# space-time cube in WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, webgl

Has somebody ever tried creating space-time cube using WebGL? I have a task to create a Space-Time cube of some geo-spatial data. Any help/examples/resources of how to do it will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Three.js is going to make your 3D Api experience a little more fun and little less 1995 looking.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/